# find number of 1 and 0 combinations in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, counter

Input:

```
            X   Y
Hyderabad   1   1
Bangalore   0   1
Goa         1   1
Chennai     0   1
Hyderabad   0   1
Goa         0   0
Chennai     0   1
Goa         0   0
Hyderabad   1   0
Chennai     0   1
Chennai     1   1
Goa         0   1
Bangalore   0   0
Bangalore   0   1
```

expected output:

```
        X   
        0   1
Y   0   3   1
    1   7   3
```

Comment: What is your problem in doing this? What specifically is not working in your code? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Great. We have the input and expected output. We are only missing the question and your attempt.

Comment: And is the input a pandas dataframe or what?

Comment: Join columns X,Y together to a tuple and do a simple Counter() from collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `pandas` dataframe, one option is to use `pandas.crosstab` to return another dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
res = pd.crosstab(df['X'], df['Y'])

print(res)

Y  0  1
X      
0  3  7
1  1  3
```

---

A `collections.Counter` solution is also possible if a dictionary result is required:

```
res = Counter(zip(df['X'].values, df['Y'].values))
```

Comment: @FHTMitchell, It's a `pd.DataFrame`. Your one is likely more efficient (which is why I +1 :)).

Comment: @jpp Are you sure? I expect `pd.crosstab` to do some vectorized calculations as opposed to the explicit `for` loop which is usually frowned upon when working with pandas

Comment: @DeepSpace, Seems like `pandas` has a fixed overhead, so for `df2 = pd.concat([df]*100)` it's slower, but for larger dataframes it's faster. Because, as you say, it's vectorised.

Comment: @Anusha, Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. If you have a new question, please [ask another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), but only if you can't find the answer elsewhere on SO. Please remember to show your attempt in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, assuming it's a pandas dataframe (called `df`)

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
for row in df.itertuples():
    counter[row.X, row.Y] += 1
```

Output:

```
 Counter({(0, 0): 3, (0, 1): 7, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 3})
```